# How Get Selected Records Counts of Grid in ASP.NET, Using JS?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have to show selected number of records from Grid, We will selected row by using checkbox column in grid. When I select number of records from grid, I have to show that selected number of records in Label. I have written code in server but page get post back to it take little bit time when I am selecting any records?I want to do this using Java script? Any Idea...

Comment: Please share your working.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lineup[]" value="1" checked>Tom</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="lineup[]" value="2">David</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="lineup[]" value="3">Sarah</input>       
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var count = 0;
            $('checkbox').change(function () {
                count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
                console.log(count);
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```